# Failed to prevent system sleep during UI testing. Error code: -536870211

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest

When I try to run my unit tests I'm getting this error.  It's weird because I have no UI tests.  Quitting Xcode and restarting doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Running the App itself before running the tests worked.

Comment: This didn't work form me. It happens now with Xcode 13. Any other hints?

Comment: Ugh.  Sorry.  I don’t currently.  Can you provide more details?